# scipy eigh gives negative eigenvalues for positive semidefinite matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, precision, eigenvalue

I am having some issues with scipy's `eigh` function returning negative eigenvalues for positive semidefinite matrices. Below is a MWE.

The `hess_R` function returns a positive semidefinite matrix (it is the sum of a rank one matrix and a diagonal matrix, both with nonnegative entries).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg as LA

def hess_R(x):
    d = len(x)
    H = np.ones(d*d).reshape(d,d) / (1 - np.sum(x))**2
    H = H + np.diag(1 / (x**2))
    return H.astype(np.float64)

x = np.array([  9.98510710e-02 ,  9.00148922e-01 ,  4.41547488e-10])
H = hess_R(x)
w,v = LA.eigh(H)
print w
```

The eigenvalues printed are

```
[ -6.74055241e-271   4.62855397e+016   5.15260753e+018]
```

If I replace `np.float64` with `np.float32` in the return statement of `hess_R` I get

```
[ -5.42905303e+10   4.62854925e+16   5.15260506e+18]
```

instead, so I am guessing this is some sort of precision issue.

Is there a way to fix this? Technically I do not need to use eigh, but I think this is the underlying problem with my other errors (taking square roots of these matrices, getting NaNs, etc.)

Comment: If I use `LA.eig` instead of 'LA.eigh', I get different eigenvalues: `[  5.15260753e+18+0.j   3.22785571e+01+0.j   4.62855397e+16+0.j]`

Comment: IMHO, your `Hess_R` function doensn't return  an actual Hessian Matrix. so `eigh` return false result in your case.

Comment: @B.M. Could you further explain what you mean? What is the function returning instead?

Comment: You may see different results depending on which LAPACK implementation your version of numpy is linked against. Using OpenBLAS v2.18 I get eigenvalues of `3.14000000e+02, 4.62855397e+16, 5.15260753e+18` with `scipy.linalg.eigh` and `1.06862038e+02, 4.62855397e+16, 5.15260753e+18` with `numpy.linalg.eigh` for your example `H` (the difference might also be partly due to the loss of precision when you print out the float values in `x` as strings).

Comment: FYI: You can replace `np.ones(d*d).reshape(d,d)` with `np.ones((d, d))`.

Answer (score 8):

I think the issue is that you've hit the limits of floating-point precision. A good rule-of-thumb for linear algebra results is that they're good to about one part in 10^8 for float32, and about one part in 10^16 for float 64. It appears that the ratio of your smallest to largest eigenvalue here is less than 10^-16. Because of this, the returned value cannot really be trusted and will depend on the details of the eigenvalue implementation you use.

For example, here are four different solvers you should have available; take a look at their results:

```
# using the 64-bit version
for impl in [np.linalg.eig, np.linalg.eigh, LA.eig, LA.eigh]:
    w, v = impl(H)
    print(np.sort(w))
    reconstructed = np.dot(v * w, v.conj().T)
    print("Allclose:", np.allclose(reconstructed, H), '\n')
```

Output:

```
[ -3.01441754e+02   4.62855397e+16   5.15260753e+18]
Allclose: True 

[  3.66099625e+02   4.62855397e+16   5.15260753e+18]
Allclose: True 

[ -3.01441754e+02+0.j   4.62855397e+16+0.j   5.15260753e+18+0.j]
Allclose: True 

[  3.83999999e+02   4.62855397e+16   5.15260753e+18]
Allclose: True
```

Notice they all agree on the larger two eigenvalues, but that the value of the smallest eigenvalue changes from implementation to implementation. Still, in all four cases the input matrix can be reconstructed up to 64-bit precision: this means the algorithms are operating as expected up to the precision available to them.